How to list all values in a column if they have values associated with them in another column in Excel?
I need to return a list in a third column of only the values from Col 1 that are fully filled out in Col 2.
In this case it would list A and C. In other words if all values A in Col 1 have corresponding values in Col 2, display value A once in Col 3 to show that its filled out and ready for further processing. B shouldn't be displayed in Col 3 because some B cells in Col 1 still have empty corresponding cells in Col 2.



Col 1
Col 2
Col 3




A
1
A


A
2
C


A
3



B
4



B




C
5



C
6



C
7



C
8




This is part of a compliance tracking document that is updated as info comes in, and once a subset of Col 1 is fully filled out in Col 2, I need to be able to tell at a glance that everyone has provided the necessary info which means I can now take the next step in the compliance process.

Use COUNTIFS to see if the number of items in column A match the count of items in column A AND those with non blanks in column B
Then FILTER out the mismatches.  Then get the UNIQUE list:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"<>")=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10)))



If the second column is filled with formula that return an empty string and not truly empty, then we need to switch the formula a bit:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,BYROW(A2:A10,LAMBDA(_z,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10=_z)*(B2:B10<>""))=COUNTIF(A2:A10,_z)))))

This now uses SUMPRODUCT and checks for an empty string.  It will also work if the cell is truly blank.


Thank you so much for the quick response, that worked!! Double thank you for providing a more complex version of the formula as well.

Follow up question:
As I work through the spill list generated in Col3, I would like the items to disappear from the list as I 'complete' them. I dont think creating a 4th 'done' column with Y/N values will work due to the nature of the spill list, and if for example I finish item A I don't think I can nest an xlookup in the formula that generates the spill list, and cant figure out how to make this work. Is there a way to make this work?

Another way could be:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10&B2:B10))))
Caveat: This approach works well for given example, but if the value in A can potentially end with a value in B better to add a delimiter:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A10&"|",A2:A10&"|"&B2:B10))))
